# how to display files from server on multiple Dropzone

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js, dropzone

I have two dropzone in a one page. One drop zone is to show images and second drop zone is to show videos. Images and videos are uploading. But i want to fetch images and videos from server and show them in dropzone. The problem is that both Images and videos is showing in a single dropzone i.e image dropzone. I want to display to images coming through server in image dropzone and videos coming through server in video drop zone. Here is the HTML:

```
<form action="{{route('test.store')}}" method="post" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneImages" type="multipart/form-data">                                                           @csrf                                                       </form> 

<form action="{{route('test.store')}}" method="post" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneVideos" type="multipart/form-data">                                                           @csrf                                                       </form>
```

Here is my JS:

```
var myDropzoneTheFirst = new Dropzone(

            '#dropzoneImages',{
            success: function (file, response) {
                console.log(response)
            },
            error: function (file, response) {
                return false;
            },
            init: function () {
                dropzone = this;
                Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
                $.ajax({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    url: '/getImages',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: { request: 'fetch' },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {

                        $.each(response, function (key, value) {
                            var mockFile = { name: value.name, size: value.size };
                            dropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
                            dropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, value.full_path);
                            dropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);

                        });

                    }
                });
            }
        });

    /* drop zone of Videos */
        var myDropzoneTheSecond = new Dropzone(

            '#dropzoneVideos',{
            success: function (file, response) {
                console.log(response)
            },
            error: function (file, response) {
                return false;
            },
            init: function () {
                dropzone = this;
                Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
                $.ajax({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    url: '/getVideos',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: { request: 'fetch' },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {

                        $.each(response, function (key, value) {
                            var mockFile = { name: value.name, size: value.size };
                            dropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
                            dropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, value.full_path);
                            dropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);

                        });

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Any help would be highly appreciable

Comment: `dropzone = this` is weird. Try calling another function in `init` instead. Then in that function, do the ajax request and use `myDropzoneTheFirst` or `myDropzoneTheSecond` for the `emit`?

Comment: any example, how to do this  ??

Answer (score 1):

Try this? Basically move the ajax `request` out of the `init`. Do the same for the 2nd Dropzone.

```
var myDropzoneTheFirst = new Dropzone(
    '#dropzoneImages',{
    success: function (file, response) {
        console.log(response)
    },
    error: function (file, response) {
        return false;
    },
    init: function () {
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    }
});

$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    url: '/getImages',
    type: 'post',
    data: { request: 'fetch' },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {

        $.each(response, function (key, value) {
            var mockFile = { name: value.name, size: value.size };
            myDropzoneTheFirst.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
            myDropzoneTheFirst.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, value.full_path);
            myDropzoneTheFirst.emit("complete", mockFile);

        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me: sidenote: i'm using dzoptions function to configure all dropzones.

```
 $('.dropzone').each(function(index){
                //declare and initalise dropzone.
                var dz= $(this).dropzone(dzoptions($(this).data('table'), $(this).data('entity')));
                //load in existing uploaded files.
                loadExistingFiles($(this).data('table'), $(this).data('entity'), dz.context.dropzone);
            });

function loadExistingFiles(table, entity, myDropzone){
    $.ajax({
     ...
     myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
    });
}
```